# Inconsistent behavior for 'required' property on HTML textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, required

I have a query form that shows up in my chat window upon pressing a button:

[image]

This query box is a TextArea generated by a JavaScript function, and hence I use JQuery to set the 'required' property:

`$('#nthelpfull-query-area').prop('required',true);`

The behavior of the textarea with the 'required' property is however very different from the usual. For example, [this is how it should normally work.](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_textarea_required)

But on my TextArea, neither does the alert popup show up on the TextArea, nor does the border of the TextArea get highlighted until I add some text in it and then remove it.

Defining the TextArea as HTML within a string and then injecting it into the container doesn't work either.

I am unable to build a snippet that replicates the chat window, but here is the dynamic code that builds the TextArea and adds it into the chat window:

```
function append_form_field(field_name, data)
{
    var mapping =
    {
        'nthelpfull': {
            'validation': '',
            'type': 'textarea',
            'class': 'text',
            'placeholder': 'Query',
            'max_length': '',
            'id': 'nthelpfull-query-area'
        }
    }
    var field = mapping[field_name]
    var el = document.createElement(field.type);
    el.setAttribute('pattern',field.validation)
    el.setAttribute('class', field.class)
    el.setAttribute('placeholder', field.placeholder)
    el.setAttribute('id', field.id)
    el.onchange = function(e)
    {
        validate_data(e, field_name, data)
    }

    $('#messages').append(el) // messages is the chat window container's id
    $('#nthelpfull-query-area').prop('required',true);
}
```

Comment: Your code appears to work fine in isolation: https://jsfiddle.net/ykjg9cs6/. Note that I did correct the missing `{}`, though, so if you have an error there that would explain the issue. I'd suggest you check the console for errors, and then add a much more complete example of the problem to the question if you still can't solve it.

Comment: How many fields do you append using this function `append_form_field`? It uses the same ID for each field `nthelpfull-query-area`. IDs **must** be unique within the document. `$('#nthelpfull-query-area')` would select first field with the id.